# Upload object to AWS S3 with a presigned URL

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, put

I would like to upload large files, via a dropzone, in an s3 bucket.

I get a presigned URL via a RESTful api (presigned URL PutObject) in an Ajax function.

PHP ajax function code :

```
$API_url = api_url;
$IdToken = $this->cognitoClient->getTokenIdCookie();
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array(
    $curl, 
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $API_url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: '.$IdToken
        ),
    )
);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$response_data = json_decode($response);
$presigned_url= $response_data->url;
return $this->json(
    array(
        "presigned_url"=>$presigned_url
    )
);
```

I would like to use this presigned URL to multipart upload the object and follow its progress.

I have already looked at the "upload" function in javascript but I don't know how to use a presigned url with this one

Comment: PHP ajax function code :  are you trying to run it under `$.ajax`?

Comment: the code I sent is in a php function which is run under $.ajax